# Visual Studio 2012 automatically adds &gt; into the programXXX.vshot.exe.config

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

```
<add name="Licensing_ProdEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/LicenceDB.csdl|res://*/LicenceDB.ssdl|res://*/LicenceDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=PCSDEV-02\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Licensing_Prod;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>**&gt;**
```

As you can see, `"&gt;"` is added at the end of the 4th line by Visual Studio 2010 itself.

I have tried to delete it many times, but each time after I run the program, it comes back.

Comment: Does that also happen when you create a fresh/new project?

Comment: @Christian.K no, I tried to add a project in this solution and also add an EntityFramework, it runs well without errors.